# Align elements horizontally to max width but wrap when parent squeezed

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Grid` which contains two `Button`s. I want the first button to align to left and the second one to the right (this is why I'm using `Grid` as the parent). When the whole window is squeezed so much that the buttons cannot be entirely visible, I want them to wrap - ie. first one stays aligned to left but the second one is moved to a new row (and preferably but not necessarily is still aligned to right). For that I'd use a `WrapPanel` but the `WrapPanel` will not fill the parent window and hence will not align the buttons to left and right.

Is there any way to get both - the horizontal alignment and wrapping?

My current code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding Attachments.Count, Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanGivenValueVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}">
  <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" Command="{Binding ExpandAttachmentsPanel}">
  </Button>
  <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" Command="{Binding DownloadAllAttachmentsCommand}">
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please add some copy/pastable code? I can imagine your issue but im too lazy to think about your Grid-surroundings (`Grid.Row="2"`)

Comment: Grid.Row="2" is really irrelevant here, isn't it. it just relates to the placement in a row in the parent element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get both - the horizontal alignment and wrapping?

There is no built-in `Panel` that gives you this behaviour but you should be able to handle the `SizeChanged` event of the `WrapPanel` and programmatically adjust the `Margin` of one of the Buttons. Something like this:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="wp" Background="Yellow" SizeChanged="WrapPanel_SizeChanged">
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Width="100">
        <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btn2" Width="100">
        <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
    </Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

---

```
private void WrapPanel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    btn1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, Math.Max(0, wp.ActualWidth - btn1.ActualWidth - btn2.ActualWidth), 0);
}
```

[image]